# How can I limit the input tag to only 10 Commas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You need an input custom that limits you to 10 commas.

When it is 10, it should be possible to modify it.

Currently, the input event works faster, so additional commas are added so it cannot be edited.

my code

```
// input props
value={relationSearch}
onChange={(e) => handleOnChangeInput(e)}
onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}

//callbackfunction
const relationCallbackFunction = {
  handleOnChangeInput: (e) => {
    setRelationSearch(e.target.value);
  },
};

// input event area
const handleOnChangeInput = (e) => {
  relationCallbackFunction.handleOnChangeInput(e);
};

const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  const currentStr = relationSearch.split(',');
  console.log(e.target.value);

  if (currentStr.length > 11) {
    e.target.value ='';
  }
};
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? what is the complete user scenario? what do you need to acomplish?

Comment: Could you provide an example that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 (O) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, (X) 
But it should also be possible to modify it.

Comment: @dev_O I mean a real example that contains all the code that is able to reproduce your issue. You can use codesanbox or put your code on GitHub and provide the link here :)

Comment: after 10 commas user shouldn't be able to enter text , is that what you need? @dev_O

Comment: Additional commas and input are not allowed, only edits should be possible.

Comment: I don't really understand the meaning of the question, but if you just want to count the number of commas in the string, I can provide you with a method for reference, you can use it as a condition to decide what to do next. e.g. `const isCommasOk = (str) => ((str || '').match(/,/g) || []).length <= 10;`

Comment: @lan This is the answer I was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this a couple of ways, but here is a simple solution. The important part here is to ensure you set your input to a controlled input, where you provide the value from react.

We need a function which will implement your logic. It should take in a string and the total number of commas you want, and limit that string to the comma amount.

Below is a very simple function that does this. It splits the string using commas, ensures the result array stays at 10 length, and returns a joined string from the resultant array.

```
function ensureCommas(str, commas = 10) {
 const commaArray = str.split(',');

 const reduced = commaArray.slice(0, commas);
 
 return reduced.join(',');

}
```

Now to use it. Here is a very simple App component which keeps the input value in state and provides this state value to the input, and has an onChange event handler which calls the above function on every key press

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function ensureCommas(str, commas = 10) {
  const commaArray = str.split(",");

  return commaArray.slice(0, 10);
}

    export default function App() {
      const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    
      const onInputChange = (e) => {
        const inputVal = e.target.value;
    
        const newInputVal= ensurecommas(inputVal , 10);
    
        setValue(newInputVal);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input value={value} onChange={onInputChange}></input>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-lucy-52mr5?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `handleKeyPress` function from the input props and update the `relationCallbackFunction` object.

```
 const relationCallbackFunction = {
  handleOnChangeInput: (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    const currentStr = value.split(",");
    if (currentStr.length <= 10) {
      setRelationSearch(value);
    }
  }
};
```